# Swift IOS Chart - Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: swift, charts

I am trying to setup a simple stacked bar chart using `iOS Chart`.

the examples all show looping though data - I just want to write one entry straight into the code.

https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/ChartsDemo-iOS/Swift/Demos/StackedBarChartViewController.swift

I am crashing at the: `let set = BarChartDataSet.`

Error is:

> Cannot convert value of type 'BarChartDataEntry' to expected argument
>   type '[ChartDataEntry]?'

```
    func _costChart( comm: Double, margin: Double, expense: Double) {

        let yVals = BarChartDataEntry(x: 0.0, yValues: [comm, margin, expense ], icon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon"))

        let set = BarChartDataSet(entries: yVals, label: "")

        let data = BarChartData(dataSets: set)

        costChart.data = data
}
```

How can I write this to confirm to the proper format?

Answer (score 0):

`BarChartDataSet` expects a nullable array of `ChartDataEntry`.
So if you want to set the data, you need to pass `nil` or a array.

```
func _costChart( comm: Double, margin: Double, expense: Double) {

   let yVals = BarChartDataEntry(x: 0.0, yValues: [comm, margin, expense ], icon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon"))

   let set = BarChartDataSet(entries: [yVals], label: "") // Passing array to entries instead of just the BarChartDataEntry (just a single item)

   let data = BarChartData(dataSets: set)

   costChart.data = data 

}
```

Comment: I needed to also add this:   let data = BarChartData(dataSets: [set] )

Comment: This solved my problems:  https://medium.com/@zzzzbh/plotting-in-ios-using-charts-framework-with-swiftui-222034a2bea6